# Facebook Tab / Post on user wall

Tags: facebook

I'v developed a Facebook tab in PHP and it pulls al the content from my web server. 
When I try to post on a users wall using the following javascript code

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'stream.publish',
     name: 'Foo Bar',
     picture: 'https://www.foobar.com/fb/img/pic_small.png',
     caption: 'Caption',
     description: 'Decription',
     message: 'Message',
   },
```

Facebook responds with the following error

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application

I found that one way to avoid this error is to register the tab as App on Facebook
and provide the Canvas URL and the Secure Canvas URL.

But what if I don't want the tab has an apps.facebook.com/appname entry url

I mean that what I want is just a FB Tab and not an app.Are there any other alternatives to post on users wall but of course using the standard fb Dialog Box  ?

Thank you in advance for your time and for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using old-fashioned FB.ui method type. Please, check the method 'feed'.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

BTW, how about checking 'App Domain' setting or 'Website' setting. I also had a similar symptom a few weeks ago, then I just set the App Domain and Website URL as my domain. Yes, I know, it's very tricky ;)